# Color-Box Not being responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I am a newbie to colorbox and I am having a silly issue with colorbox-rendering on different screen-resolutions and I was hoping to get some help on this.

I am basically trying to display part of an external-html file in color box. I have been able to do that, but it doesnt seem to work the same way on other devices with different screen resolutions. With bigger resolution screens, the rendering included stray elements too..
I have tried to set the max-Height values, but no luck with that either. 
For more clarity here is a snap-shot -- 
[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
$("#id").colorbox({ 
    href:function(){
        return $(this).attr('href') + '#div1';
    },
    iframe: true,
    scrolling: false, 
    width: "50%", 
    height: "58%",
    closeButton:true,
    opacity:0.1
});
```

Comment: Post snapshot link, someone could fix it

Comment: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img834/2539/m8qp.png

Comment: @user3573997 what about the colorbox `parent` element width/height, is it behaving correctly?

Comment: If (parent-element) you mean the html-file calling color-box plug-in, then not really!!

Comment: @user3573997 I actually mean the element wrapping `#id` element which is colorbox, if its parent is not responsive it's possible that the problem is there

Comment: oh, okay.. The height-width is working fine on those elements..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a awnser on your question but if you want to display a other html file in a box that change size dependent on how big/small the screen is try to:

```
<iframe src="your_filename.html" width="40%" height="40%">
<p>A error message.</p>
</iframe>
```

The thing that will happend is that the iframe (with your html file) will be 40% of your screen heigth and the same with the width.